# Inserting average rows in tensorflow tensor

Tags: arrays, numpy, insert, tensorflow

I have the following function in numpy:

```
A = np.array([[1, 2, 3],
          [4, 5, 6],
          [7, 8, 9],
          [10, 11, 12]])


def insert_row_averages(A, n=2):
    slice2 = A[n::n]
    v = (A[n-1::n][:slice2.shape[0]] + slice2)/2.0
    np.insert(A.astype(float),n*np.arange(1,v.shape[0]+1),v,axis=0)
```

which basically takes the average of the above and below rows and inserts it between the two, at every n intervals.

Any idea on how I can do this one in Tensorflow? Specifically what can I use instead of np.insert, since there does not seem to be an equivalent function.

Answer (score 1):

You could use an initialization based approach to solve it, like so -

```
def insert_row_averages_iniitalization_based(A, n=1):

    # Slice and compute averages   
    slice2 = A[n::n]
    v = (A[n-1::n][:slice2.shape[0]] + slice2)/2.0

    # Compute number of rows for o/p array
    nv = v.shape[0]
    nrows = A.shape[0] + nv

    # Row indices where the v values are the inserted in o/p array
    v_rows = (n+1)*np.arange(nv)+n

    # Initialize o/p array
    out = np.zeros((nrows,A.shape[1]))

    # Insert/assign v in output array
    out[v_rows] = v  # Assign v

    # Create 1D mask of length equal to no. of rows in o/p array, such that its
    # TRUE at places where A is to be assigned and FALSE at places where values
    # from v were assigned in previous step.
    mask = np.ones(nrows,dtype=bool)
    mask[v_rows] = 0

    # Use the mask to assign A.
    out[mask] = A
    return out
```

Comment: That looks nice, but it still uses numpy instead of tensorflow. My problem is that I can't really seem to find the tensorflow equivalents which I could use to translate this code.

Comment: @Qubix So, `tensorflow` doesn't support initialization of arrays?

Comment: I was saying that functions like "np.setdiff1d" might not have an equivalent. I'm looking through the documentation right now.

Comment: @Qubix Replaced with simpler functions. Check out the edits!

Comment: Thanks, will try to implement in tesorflow and write the answer here, if it works.

Comment: the part after " # Insert v and then in the leftover places the data array A itself" is not really possible (as far as I could find) in Tensorflow. Could you explain a bit what that does, since it is not clear to me. v seems to be a matrix of all average vectors, not a row. Any other way to do it?

Comment: @Qubix Added few more comments. Can't propose any simpler method, sorry.